# Line counting C++

Tags: c++, lines, counting

I'm working with this peace of that count the logical lines in a program, omitting comments and black lines. The counting line is working, but I don't know how to omit the comment lines, I try

```
if (line == "//")
{
    comment++;
}
```

but it only checks for lines that start with `"//"` and if there's text next to that it doesn't count that as a comment line :/

At the end when I know the total lines and total comment lines, I will subtract `totalLines-commentLines` to know the real program number lines.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numlines = 0;
    int comment = 0;
    string line;

    ifstream myfile("wr.cpp");
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        getline(myfile, line);
        if (line == "//")
        {
            comment++;
        }
        if (line == "/**/")
        {
            comment++;
        }
        ++numlines;
    }
    cout << "Number of lines: " << numlines << endl;
    cout << "Number of comment lines: " << comment << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are doing it just for fun and to learn, it is OK. If you really need a tool to do this and you are using Linux, [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) is a good tool that does this for your (most likely available in your Linux distro, no need to compile it yourself). If you google a little, you will certainly find other similar tools. In any case, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think your methodology is...flawed.

Consider a line like:

```
int x = 1;    // starting from 1 because [some reason]
```

As your code stands right now, it counts only as a non-comment line. As you've described what you'd like to do, it would count only as a comment line.

In reality, tThis contains both code and a comment, so you'd normally want to count it as both code *and* comment, not just one or the other.

Doing this job well is decidedly non-trivial. Obvious problems you encounter are:

1. a string that contains something that looks like a comment
2. line continuation
3. trigraphs

   - Can hide line continuation
   - Can create a false comment delimiter
4. Multi-line C-ctyle comments
5. `#if`s, `#ifdef`s, etc.

There are probably more issues than that (though are just what occurred to me immediately), but those should be enough to give at least a general flavor.

Bottom line: I think to get very far with this (at all) you're doing to at least need a reasonably complete/accurate [C++ lexer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7051822/179910). You probably don't need a full parser, but I think any attempt that doesn't use a full C++ lexer s almost certain to fail, probably quite badly and quite frequently.

Comment: Better yet, the OP should use an existing tool rather than waste time writing a new one.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I can't entirely agree. Most of the tools I've seen were open to substantial improvement--many would fail around half the tests I've mentioned above.