# Using BOOST Tokenizer to display delimiter and to not tokenize a string in quotes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-tokenizer

I am using BOOST Tokenizer to break a string into toekn. Basically the tokens will be used to create a compiler for VSL based on c/c++. What i wanted to ask that is it possible that the delimiter defined created using

```
char_separator<char> sep("; << ");
```

be also displayed
for example if i use Boost tokenizer on string

```
string s= "cout<<hello;"
```

it should make the following tokens

```
cout
<<
hello
;
```

Also how can i ensure that it does not convert tokenize something in quotes
like

```
string s= "hello my \"name is\" Hassan"
```

should be converted to following tokens

```
hello
my
name is
Hassan
```

Comment: I doubt that Boost tokenizer is really up to this task ("doubt" as in, "I would be flabbergasted if it could even come close"). Tokenizing C++ source code is a fairly non-trivial task. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7051822/179910) is a possibility that might get you started.

Comment: Oh wait. Just noticed that you actually want to parse a programming language. Adding links to samples in my answer

Answer (score 3):

I suggest boost spirit: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf06c380a6d0461)**

**Edit** See also http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    std::string const input = "cout<<hello;my \"name is\" Hassan";

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> delimiter = qi::char_("; ") | qi::string("<<");
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> quoted    = '"' >> *~qi::char_('"') > '"';
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> word      = +((quoted | qi::char_) - delimiter);

    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    if (qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), *(word >> delimiter), tokens))
    {
        for(auto& token : tokens)
            std::cout << "'" << token <<  "'\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'cout'
'<<'
'hello'
';'
'my'
' '
'name is'
' '
'Hassan'
```

Comment: The problem i am facing is when i add more words to the delimiter i end up not completely parsing the code. If i try adding qi::string("<") to the delimiter it does not parse the whole code , it gets stuck on the line 
include < iostream.h >
If instead i use
qi::string("< ")
it works fine but then does not create tokens for x<y

Comment: Congratulations.  You've found out that tokenizing is more interesting than simple string comparison.  I suggest you look into Boost Spirit Lex. And Boost Wave in particular (which implements a full c++preprocessor)