# Tokenizing a wrapped string using boost::tokenizer

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize

I am parsing a custom meta data file where the separator is a space `' '`. The meta data file contains strings where the space separator should be omitted. So `"\"This Space\""` is one token and `"This Space"` should be two tokens.

There is a questions like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22120842/using-boost-tokenizer-to-display-delimiter-and-to-not-tokenize-a-string-in-quote) with an answer on how to get a result without using `boost::tokenizer`. This seems like a default task for a tokeniser and i assume that this should be possible using `boost::tokenizer`.

I wrote an example to show what i did so far:

```
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using data = std::vector<string>;

data buildExpected()
{
    string s[] = {"This", "is one of", "42", "lines" };
    return data(s, s + 4);
}

data tokenizeLine(string line)
{
    using namespace boost;
    data d;
    char_separator<char> sep("\" ");
    tokenizer<char_separator<char>> tokens(line, sep);
    for (string tok : tokens) d.push_back(tok);
    return d;
}

void logData(string id, data &d)
{
    string line = "(" + id + "):";
    bool more = 0;
    for (auto s : d)
    {
        if (more) line += "; ";
        more = 1;
        line += s;
    }
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}

void main()
{
    string line = "This \"is one of\" 42 lines";
    data expected = buildExpected();
    data actual = tokenizeLine(line);
    logData("expected", expected);
    logData("actual  ", actual);

}
```

This is the output on my system:

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Tokenizer doesn't handle quotes. Its functionality is very simple - just split to tokens on each separator occurrence. You need to handle parenthesis yourself.

Comment: I guess i need to up the complexity and use a different library.

Comment: it shouldn't be really difficult to implement what you need with Boost.Tokenizer, especially if you don't need to support included quotes, you know something like "quote with "sub quote""

Comment: I rolled things like it in the past, but i would rather use something off the shelve. For now i will just loosely couple the tokenizer part as good as i can and replace it when it becomes a problem.