# How to actually see if the compiler error is Lexical Error or Syntax Error?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, compiler-warnings, lexical-analysis

Is there a way using some tool to see if some program that gave compiler error is Lexical Error or Syntax Error in C. I know mostly which errors are produced by Lexer and which by Parser, but I still have some doubts about some of the unusual cases where I'm confused which is which. So to be kind of sure I want to know that in the compilation error message, but the one I'm using (DEV C) doesn't provide much.

Comment: Human eye can look at a token and see if it matches the C requirements.  If needed you could take preprocessor output and run it through flex.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7051694/1216776

Comment: The C language does not really distinguish between various error types, and some errors are not obviously either parser or lexer errors. (In fact, many token errors are not detected by the initial lexical scan, but rather are detected in translation phase 7 when the preprocessing tokens need to be converted to parser tokens.)